# Не скроллится HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview

Не скроллится никаким образом HorizontalScrollView. Мне нужно чтобы View выходила за экран.
У меня все реализовано на android_weight и чтоб она выходила за край я этой последней вьюшке поставил layout_weight="1". Вообще пробовал по всякому, не помогает. Что я упустил?
Мой код выглядит так:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/specialTasksTextLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/bebasneue_bold"
                android:text="ОСОБЫЕ ЗАДАНИЯ"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_flex"
                    android:text="Эксклюзивно для "
                    android:textColor="#59FFFFFF"
                    android:textFontWeight="400"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_7sdp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/bebasneue_bold"
                    android:text="PREMIUM"
                    android:textColor="#FF7B00"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_8sdp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/bebasneue_bold"
                    android:text="PASS"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_8sdp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/specialTasksTextLayout"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:scrollbars="horizontal"

            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
            android:scrollbarTrackHorizontal="@drawable/bp_scrollbar_vertical_track"
            android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@drawable/bp_scrollbar_vertical_thumb"
            android:scrollbarSize="@dimen/_10sdp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/specialTasksRV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                tools:itemCount="5"
                tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_battlepass_task"
                tools:orientation="vertical" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.02" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/special2TasksRV"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                tools:itemCount="5"
                tools:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                tools:listitem="@layout/item_battlepass_task"
                tools:orientation="vertical" />
        </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `layout_weight` делит ширину контейнера между элементами - соответственно сам контейнер должен быть шире экрана. У вас не понятно как это должно выглядеть: _"чтобы View выходила за экран"_ - это насколько? По какой логике должна определяться ширина?

Comment: Так HorizontalScrollView за экран то выходит, а скроллиться не хочет. Там такой дизайн что последний раздел должен недалеко выходить за экран и скроллиться горизонтально.

Comment: Единственное, как удалось это пофиксить - присвоить minWidth LinearLayout'у. Жаль по другому нельзя